# Are there a way to hold the password?

Tags: android

In Android Device Administration, I know `resetPassword(String password, int flags)` can reset the password. But, my wish is that I will hold old password before reseting it. In this way, I can, if user wants, rescue the password. Are there a way to hold the password ? Moreover, how can I get password from system ?

NOTE: My application is system app.

Comment: I'm not sure about Android but usually passwords are not stored *"as-is"*. Only their hash (or an encrypted version of the password) is stored, not the real plain-text password. When you input a password, it is hashed and compared with the stored hash.

Comment: @m0skit0 is this hash function ; is it one way or can be solved if I know the key ?

Comment: Hashes have no key and cannot be reversed except by brute force. Even so you cannot be sure if that was the original password since they're not bijective (different passwords can result in the same hash value).

Comment: @m0skit0 where is the hashed password stored ?

Comment: As I said *"I'm not sure about Android"*. I don't know where they are stored.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot get the password. It is indeed hashed, and the device technically doesn't 'know' it. Additionally, since pretty much any app can become a system administrator (if the user confirms), any app would be able to retrieve the password, which is a bad idea.

Comment: That's why they're hashed :)

Comment: Where is the hashed password stored ?

Comment: In `/data/system/password.key`, but you also need to get the hash from the system settings database. Unless you want to check against the hash it is not particularly useful. Cracking it on the device will usually be quite slow, if that's what you are thinking about.